# ASP.NET WebMethod parameter or Session?

Tags: asp.net, session, webmethod

I have a `WebMethod` that I call with a parameter from javascript with the `foo` parameter. I also have the `foo` value stored inside the session.

Which value should I use? Is there any considerazione about security?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, an advanced user can always edit the client code and change the html and js function, if others `Foos` are predictable, a malicious user could swap the value `Foo` in the js function, and use it to access/handle protected data.

Besides, if you already got the value in the session, why to pass it?

Comment: I just do not remeber that I had the value there :D

Answer (score 1):

If you already have the foo value in your session and both value are same, then it would be prefered to use session value instead.
Use value which is stored in session.

Happy Coding